# Website says connection is not secure when opened without www but works fine with www. I am using https

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, https, dns

I have configured domain setting to open my website on www.websitename.com and with only websitename.com. I am using https on aws loadbalancer and it is a django website. The problem is website opens fine when opened with https://www.websitename.com but when I open is with https://websitename.com it opens the website but with message saying connection is not secure.

Django Settings File.

```
        SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT         = True
        SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE       = True
        CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE          = True
        SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Could someone help to figure out the problem I am not sure if it's the aws or some configuration error in settings file.

Good: https://www.websitename.com

Connection Error on: https://websitename.com

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get your point. Both links give the same certificate error: `Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN` If you accept certificate error your are forwarded to same website saying the desired domain is for sale.

Comment: No, It doesn't give any error when opened with full url like www.websitename.com

Comment: But when I open it with just websitename.com It gives connection error.

Comment: please try a different browser or delete all browser settings and history - you might have accepted the certificate once and  don't see the errors any more.

Comment: It still doesn't work on Safari even if I clear history and then use it. Although it works on other browsers now.

Comment: Both names must be in the list of the subject alternative names (SANs) of your certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined **websitename.com** in the list of subject alternative names (SANs) of your certificate? You should put both names in your list of domains.